# Angular2 Router - window.opener: Lost Change Detection at forwar

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, prototype-programming

When I open a popup for OAuth, and returning via

```
window.opener.closeCallbackFunction();
```

then my ChangeDetection isn't working anymore on the forwarded page.

```
function _window(): any {
  return window;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
})
export class ConsultantRegisterComponent {

    constructor() {
    }

    openPopup() {
        let _this = this;
        let selfWindow = _window();
        let popup = lib.PopupCenter('/RegisterWithFacebook', 'Sign In', 600, 400);

        selfWindow.closeCallbackFunction = function () {
            popup.close();
            _this.forward.call(_this);
        };

    }

    forward() {
        this.router.navigate(['/register-oauth']);
    }
}
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, googled a solution: just needed to do it with NgZone:

```
function _window(): any {
  return window;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
})
export class ConsultantRegisterComponent {

    constructor(private _zone:NgZone) {
    }

    openPopup() {
        let _this = this;
        let selfWindow = _window();
        let popup = lib.PopupCenter('/RegisterWithFacebook', 'Sign In', 600, 400);

        selfWindow.closeCallbackFunction = function () {
            popup.close();
            _this.forward.call(_this);
        };

    }

    forward() {
        this._zone.run(() => {
           this.router.navigate(['/register-oauth']);
        });
    }
}
```